# RadContextMenu auto close prevent on click (WinForms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, telerik

I use telerik UI for WinForms project(not WPF)
How to prevent auto close of `RadContextMenu` when user clicks on item on it? Now, after mouse click on any item, it closes. In WinForms there is `ContextMenuStrip.AutoClose` property to prevent autoclosing. Is there analogue of the property on Telerik `RadContextMenu`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have asked the question on Telerik forum , they correct answered me:

We do not have such а property, but you can very easily prevent the menu from closing by using the DropDownClosing event:

```
void menu_DropDownClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```